# Correctly deleting child elements in PHP using DOMDocument and DOMXPath

Tags: php, domdocument, removechild, domxpath

This was previous another question, but we won't talk about that. I am isolating a number of sections in a third party HTML document. When matching some, I need to remove certain tags from the result. The code I found for this on SO was:

```
$name = $xpath->query("//div[@class='leftColBig']//h3")->item(0);
// remove <span>
foreach($xpath->query("//span", $name) as $node)
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

This has the unfortunate side effect of not just deleting the child from $name, but the entire DOMDocument :( How can I isolate the removeChild just to the section I found using the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$xpath->query("//span", $name)
```

Do:

```
$xpath->query("span", $name)
```

`//nodename` matches all nodes no matter what their parent is. $contextnode is ignored when your query starts with `//`.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. now if only i could get 6 hours of my life back. :)